# Mockito : Is there any way to call/run a real method with fake data.

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Trying to invoke a method with some fake data(test data). i understand that return value can be overridden doReturn(), thenReturn(), but scenario here is to override argument which is going to be passed and not the return value or behaviour of the method. And actual service class,

**DataService**

```
public class DataService extends IntentService {

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
       DataAcquirer.getInstance()
                    .subscribe(DataService.this,dataCallback);
}

DataAcquirer.DataCallback dataCallback = new DataAcquirer.DataCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Data data) {
         //some process here
        }  
      };
}
```

and then the question is how do i run that `onResult(Data data)` method in test class and pass test data(hardcoded data).

**DataServiceTest**

```
@MediumTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class DataServiceTest {

@Rule
public ServiceTestRule mServiceTestRule =  new ServiceTestRule();

    @Mock
    DataService mockDataService;

    @Mock
    Data data;

    @Mock
    DataCallback callback;

    @Mock
    DataAcquirer mockDA;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDataProcessing() throws InterruptedException {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, DataFetchService.class);
        intent.putExtra(res.getString(R.string.type), "options_one");
        mServiceTestRule.startService(intent);


        data.temp =(float) -15.37;
        //This should run actual work in DataService with the data provided here 
        mockDataService.callback.onResult(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're testing the "DataService" class, then it shouldn't be mocked, otherwise you won't be able to test any of it's behavior. Same goes for your dataCallback; Because they are mocked, you don't get to execute the code you wrote for them, the methods are simply replaced by stubs.

Comment: Cool. its works thanks man

Comment: am able to access that method but it says NullPointer on context wherever it used. @JaceJMcPherson.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting "mocking" the wrong way.

The idea is: you create @Mock (mocked) objects for things that your *class under test* depends on.

In that sense: you could simply do

```
@Mock
Intent mockedIntent;
```

and then **pass** that mocked object when calling your *class under test*.

Answer (score 0):

How to pass test data to DataCallback? I would say by mocking DataAcquirer (or injecting test one) and let the service do the work instead of manually calling onResult(...).

```
    package test;

    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.mockito.Mockito;
    import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
    import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;
    import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
    import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
    import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

    import test.DataServiceTest.DataAcquirer;
    import test.DataServiceTest.DataAcquirer.DataCallback;

    import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;

    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest(DataAcquirer.class)
    public class DataServiceTest {

      @Before
      public void setUp() {
        DataAcquirer mockDataAcquirer = Mockito.mock(DataAcquirer.class);
        Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer() {
          @Override
          public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            DataCallback dataCallback = invocation.getArgumentAt(0, DataCallback.class);

            dataCallback.onResult("test data");

            return null;
          }
        }).when(mockDataAcquirer).subscribe(any(DataCallback.class));

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DataAcquirer.class);
        Mockito.when(DataAcquirer.getInstance()).thenReturn(mockDataAcquirer);
      }

      @Test
      public void testName() {
        DataAcquirer dataAcquirer = DataAcquirer.getInstance();

        dataAcquirer.subscribe(new DataCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onResult(String data) {
            assertThat(data, is("test data"));
          }
        });
     }

      public static class DataAcquirer {

        public static DataAcquirer getInstance() {
          return new DataAcquirer();
        }

        private DataAcquirer() {
        }

        public void subscribe(DataCallback dataCallback) {
          // real implementation
        }

        public static class DataCallback {

          public void onResult(String data) {
          }

        }
      }
    }
```